# How to remove color from zsh ls?

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I met some problems when configure zsh with oh-my-zsh on MAC OSX.

When I type 'ls -l' command, some of the output is blue. I don't know where it's from. I didn't set anything like this:

[image: colors in ls -l output]

I guess is it from $CLICOLOR, when I 'echo $CLICOLOR' ,it returns 1. While I didn't find where to modify it.

And by the way, how to customize the color of ls output when using zsh? I tried environment variable like $LSCOLORS in ~/.zshrc which does not work.

Playing with zsh is quiet different from bash and I'm new to zsh. Hope somebody can help me with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107371/186840 which has been answered already. On macOS, color is enabled by the `-G` flag but the rest stays the same.

Comment: @Palle That works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, but I still want to tell some difference between CLICOLOR and 'ls -G' after I tried them many times.

The problem I presented could be raised by both 'CLICOLOR' and 'ls -G' on MAC. If

```
export CLICOLOR = 1
```

is added to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc, it means you allowed to use

```
export LSCOLOR = 'blabla'
```

to define the colors of ls command. This is independent to 'ls -G', which can also highlight 'ls' output but you cannot customize the color of it. (perhaps there is a not known way you can).

So try both when you meet this problem.